# Prevent Address Book (Contacts) to quit when closing the window

Tags: macos, contacts

The Address Book quits when closing the window. Did anybody find a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If the application is designed like there is no way to change it. If you want to keep the application open and not see it you can hide it:

- from the menu "Address Book" → "Hide Address Book"
- with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

Comment: Yes, that's what I do (if I remember). I find it strange, though, that Apple deviates from the standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Those settings are defined when the code for the app is compiled. You can’t edit those by modifying a `plist` or something. I don’t see the reason behind the behaviour you are looking for. If you could give a reason, maybe I can suggest a workaround.

Comment: Usually an app und OS X does not quit when you close the window. Rather it remains active. I do not understand why Apple is starting to change this standard behaviour with some apps, e.g. the address book.

Comment: Notice that it happens only with small utility apps like Contacts, Reminders, etc and not with big apps like Calendar, Safari, etc. It is the same on iOS. Big apps are just sent to the background while small apps like Weather and Reminders quit.

Comment: But even a small app like the address book takes a noticeable amount of time to start (even on my 27" iMac with 12 GB RAM) where I expect immediate availability after the first start.

Comment: That’s something wrong with your iMac. I have a 7200rpm HD and 8 GB RAM and Contacts starts in 1 bounce.

Comment: I would not say that because it happens on two different iMacs (private and at office). Opening the address book most probably is not solely a local activity if you use iCloud and/or an Exchange Server in the background. I also don't say that it takes several seconds, but it is a noticeable delay which I would to avoid – the address book must be available immediately.